# How do you go about simplifying this such that you can use the geometric series equation.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you go about simplifying this such that you can use the geometric series equation.

$$ \sum\limits_{c=0}^\infty c (2/32)^c = 16/225 $$

Comment: Integrate term by term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|x|<1$ you have that \begin{align}\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}cx^c&=0+x+2x^2+3x^3+\dots\\&=x(1+2x+3x^2+\dots)\\[0.3cm]&=x\left(x'+(x^2)'+(x^3)'+\dots\right)=x\left(1'+x'+(x^2)'+(x^3)'+\dots\right)\\[0.2cm]&=x\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}(x^c)'=x\left(\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}x^c\right)'=x\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)'=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\end{align} Now let $x=2/32$ to conclude.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$S=\sum_{c=0}^\infty ca^c=\sum_{c=1}^\infty ca^c=\sum_{c=0}^\infty(c+1)a^{c+1}=aS+a\sum_{c=0}^\infty a^c.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n r^n = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=i}^{\infty} r^n$$

Why? Try writing out a couple first terms in the series on the right.